# Best way to implement interthread communication in FreeRTOS? - checking the state of a lwIP cable

Tags: c, multithreading, multitasking, freertos, lwip

I want to make a lwip cable on/off bulletproof with DHCP on and a TCP connection. Both solutions work ok but I don't know which one is the more sensible and right. (I am afraid of wrong context function calls)

- First solution:

I call:

```
tcpip_init(network_init, &net);
```

and then after that:

```
xTaskCreate(hc_task, ( signed portCHAR * ) "send hc",1536u, NULL, TCPIP_THREAD_PRIO, NULL);
```

So there are 2 threads the main `lwIP` thread and the `hc_task` thread. `hc_task` is:

```
static void hc_task(void *parameters)
{
    struct hc_message mes;
    mes.client_port_number = 4839;
    mes.host_addres = "192.168.1.183\0";
    mes.host_add[0] = 192;
    mes.host_add[1] = 168;
    mes.host_add[2] = 1;
    mes.host_add[3] = 183;
    mes.host_file = "test/data.php\0";
    mes.host_port_number = 80;
    mes.target = "http://192.168.1.183/test/data.php\0";

    transferEnd = 0;
    numberOfPacketsProc = 0;
    totalRecievedSize = 0;

    hc_send(&mes, 0);
    vTaskDelete(NULL);
}
```

`hc_send` does a TCP connection to some page to download it.

Then I have a polling timer with an interval of 2 seconds which checks PHY and reads the cable state:

```
if cable is on  -> ok
if cable is off -> call netif_set_link_down(pxNetIfInUse);
```

Now next time when the cable goes on I call:

```
netif_set_link_up(pxNetIfInUse);
```

I am guessing that is correct to call these functions in a timer interrupt.

- Second solution:

The second method is that the timer interrupt sends a message to the main `lwip` thread:

```
Link off -> res = sys_mbox_trypost(toOutput, &msg);
```

The timer interrupt sends the main lwip thread a message to call either:

```
netif_set_link_up(pxNetIfInUse);
```

or:

```
netif_set_link_down(pxNetIfInUse); //(in lwip main thread)
```

I have a global variable to store the cable state (saved from that timer interrupt), and I check it in the main `lwip` thread to call the right function (link up or down).

So I am asking which solution is the better/right way to do it: in the timer interrupt call link down or up (these are lwip functions) OR the timer interrupt sends a message to main lwIP thread?

My configuration:
Microprocessor LPC1768
- LAN8720 PHY
- FreeRTOS 7.4
- lwip 1.4.1
- DHCP included
- TCP/IP included

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some days in thanks to lwip user support (thanks to Pomeroy Marty, Sylvain Rochet, Richard and other who hellped me - [link to debate](http://lists.libreplanet.org/archive/html/lwip-users/2013-05/msg00039.html)) forum I came to answer:

In a timer call:

```
//link off
printf( "Interrupt LINK OFF\n"  );
iface_up = 0;
resultCall = tcpip_callback_with_block(tcp_set_link_status, NULL, 0);

//link on
printf("Interrupt LINK ON\n"  );
resultCall = tcpip_callback_with_block(tcp_set_link_status, NULL, 0);
```

So the function below will be executed in thread context of main lwip TCP/IP thread which is correct:

```
void tcp_set_link_status(void)
{
        if(cableState == 0)
        {
                printf("TCP callback printf set link down \n");
                netif_set_link_down(pxNetIfInUse);
        }
        else
        {
                printf("TCP callback Printf set link up \n");
                netif_set_link_up(pxNetIfInUse);
        }
}
```